# Why is 1 plus 31 zeros not a valid integer, if bit flags are 31 length, plus one negative/positive flag?

Tags: java, int, bit-manipulation

According to [this](https://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=bitManipulation), in the around-fourth paragraph below the first table, says

> In general, we will use an integer to represent a set on a domain of up to 32 values (or 64, using a 64-bit integer), with a 1 bit representing a member that is present and a 0 bit one that is absent.

If that's true, then why does this 32 digit binary number exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("10000000000000000000000000000000", 2));
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
"10000000000000000000000000000000"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE is 2^^31 - 1 and your number is one more, 2^^31.  For signed integers, the top bit says it is negative.  This is how twos-complement works.

Answer (score 4):

In base 2, 10000000000000000000000000000000 (that's 31 zeroes) is 2^31.  A Java `int` is a 32-bit twos complement representation of numbers between -2^31 and 2^31-1; and this range of course does not include 2^31.  That's why this value can't be converted to an `int` - although a `long` would be fine.

If you have a Java `int` whose bits are 10000000000000000000000000000000 (still 31 zeroes), that's -2^31.

It's not true that the first bit of a Java `int` is a positive/negative flag.  It's simply a digit with place value of -2^31.

Answer (score 2):

It exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE` because it *really does* exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. It's `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`, which you can absolutely calculate in `int`-space and you can write it down as `0x80000000` or as `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, but it'll be negative.

Which is why `parseInt` complains.

You just can't parse it that way - you *can* absolutely represent a bitvector with the 32nd bit set with an `int`. The "sign bit" (which is a misleading name, but we seem to be stuck with it) is just a normal bit like any other bit. Its special meaning only comes into play for:

- converting to/from String
- converting to a wider or floating point type
- division and remainder
- right shift, see `>>` vs `>>>`
- comparisons except equality, for example `1 > 0x80000000`. You can compare `long x` and `y` as if they were unsigned with `(x ^ Long.MIN_VALUE) < (y ^ Long.MIN_VALUE)` (for `int` you can cast to `long` and mask with `0xffffffffL` of course)

The "sign bit" is just an other bit without special meaning for:

- addition and subtraction
- bitwise operations (including left shift)
- multiplication
- equality testing
- converting to a narrower type

If you're interpreting your `int` as a bitvector, the "sign bit" will just be a normal bit, but you must take care that all the operations you do on it agree on that.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer:

---

I figured it out. [This](http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html) webpage cleared it up for me:

> Java integers are 32 bits. The highest bit is reserved for plus or minus sign. So you can set/unset 31 one-bit flags

My misunderstanding was that bit flags *used* the 32nd bit in an integer in this way, as the negative or positive marker, *as if it were an option to do so*. But Java defines an integer that way, so it's not an option--it's a result or by-product of that definition. An integer has only 31 bits that represent the number itself. The 32nd serves as the plus-minus.

(After writing this, I can see that it makes no sense to even say "bit flags use" anything. Bit flags are concept, the integer is a concrete type.)

---

Update: Some observations:

`Integer.MIN_VALUE` equals `-2147483648`, which in binary, is

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

The first bit indicates negative. It's a sign bit *in this situation* because this is a signed integer (`Integer.MIN_VALUE` is negative, and min-and-max are equidistant to zero). Were it an unsigned integer, it would just be another value-bit.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html:

Signed:

> int: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -231 and a maximum value of 231-1.

Unsigned:

> In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 232-1. Use the Integer class to use int data type as an unsigned integer. See the section The Number Classes for more information. Static methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic operations for unsigned integers.

Again: `Integer.MIN_VALUE` equals `-2147483648`, which in binary, is

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

Changing that "sign bit" to a zero does not make this `2147483648` (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`). It makes it

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

which is *zero*. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in binary is

```
01111111111111111111111111111111
```

Switching the "sign bit" to a one doesn't make it `MIN_VALUE`.

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Attempting to parse this fails, because 32 bits are too large for *the value portion* of a signed integer:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("10000000000000000000000000000000", 2));
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
"10000000000000000000000000000000"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Rather

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

is

```
 1111111111111111111111111111111
```

with a "sign bit" indicating negative. A binary digit with thirty-two ones is `-1`. I can't  get my mind around why at the moment. I also don't know how to parse a negative (signed) binary. This

```
Integer.parseInt("-1111111111111111111111111111111", 2)
```

is equal to

```
   num:   -2147483647
          10000000000000000000000000000001
```

So it's overflowing or something...

Testing class:

```
public class BinaryNumberTest  {
  public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
     testNum(Integer.parseInt("-1111111111111111111111111111111", 2), "-1111111111111111111111111111111");
     testNum(Integer.MAX_VALUE, "Integer.MAX_VALUE");
     testNum(0, "0");
     testNum(Integer.MIN_VALUE, "Integer.MIN_VALUE");
  }
  private static final void testNum(int num, String description)  {
     System.out.println(description + ": " + num);
     System.out.println();

     int numMinus1 = num - 1;
     System.out.println("   num-1: " + numMinus1);
     System.out.println("          " + get32BitZeroPaddedBinaryNum(numMinus1));

     System.out.println("   num:   " + num);
     System.out.println("          " + get32BitZeroPaddedBinaryNum(num));

     int numPlus1 = num + 1;
     System.out.println("   num+1: " + numPlus1);
     System.out.println("          " + get32BitZeroPaddedBinaryNum(numPlus1));
     System.out.println();
  }

  private static final String get32BitZeroPaddedBinaryNum(int num)  {
     return  String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(num)).replace(' ', '0');
  }
}
```

Output:

```
-1111111111111111111111111111111: -2147483647

   num-1: -2147483648
          10000000000000000000000000000000
   num:   -2147483647
          10000000000000000000000000000001
   num+1: -2147483646
          10000000000000000000000000000010

Integer.MAX_VALUE: 2147483647

   num-1: 2147483646
          01111111111111111111111111111110
   num:   2147483647
          01111111111111111111111111111111
   num+1: -2147483648
          10000000000000000000000000000000

0: 0

   num-1: -1
          11111111111111111111111111111111
   num:   0
          00000000000000000000000000000000
   num+1: 1
          00000000000000000000000000000001

Integer.MIN_VALUE: -2147483648

   num-1: 2147483647
          01111111111111111111111111111111
   num:   -2147483648
          10000000000000000000000000000000
   num+1: -2147483647
          10000000000000000000000000000001
```

Comment: I'm confused. In your title you explicitly say that you have a number of 1 + 31 (= 32) characters. And you know that there is 1 bit used for the flag. What made you think you could still create an integer with 32 bits?

Comment: Edit: dumb hasty comment.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I clarified my answer a bit.

Comment: That web page that you linked to is very misleading.  The highest bit is absolutely NOT reserved for a plus or minus sign, as it claims.

Comment: @DavidWallace The MSB in a signed integer is the sign bit. For the purpose of explanation, I think it is good enough. What else would the MSB signify in a signed integer?

Comment: @anonymous The MSB is a digit like any other, except that its place value is negative, rather than positive.  It is NOT a "sign bit."  It just happens that it is 1 in negative integers, but 0 in positive integers and zero.  You can test this by taking any positive `int` that you like, then doing a bitwise OR to switch on the MSB.  The value that you get will in general NOT be the negative of the value you started with.

Comment: @DavidWallace To do the test you suggest of simply flipping the MSB to 1 goes beyond the argument that the MSB is a sign bit. The fact is the MSB is a sign bit to denote a negative number. I think you are mistakenly thinking that I am suggesting that a `5` will turn into `-5` simply by setting the MSB. I **AM NOT** suggesting that at all.

Comment: The MSB is a value bit to denote -2^31.  If you misleadingly refer to it a "sign bit", you incorrectly imply that it doesn't have a value of its own.  Please stop calling it a "sign bit".

Comment: @DavidWallace I guess I'll have to disagree with you. I don't know about you, but one only needs to check the MSB bit to see if a number is going to be positive or negative. You may have another way. But this works for me.

Comment: @aliteralmind after reading your update and I'm impressed by your efforts in trying to understand what is going on under the hoods. Let's go back to the argument of how to tell a number whether it is positive or negative. In 2's complement signed integer, the number is negative when MSB is 1. Now the other thing is, given a 32 bit binary number, how do you determine what number it is? For positive numbers, it is trivial. For negative numbers, you flip the bits and add 1. For example, the bits 0xFFFFFFFF, the MSB is 1 so it is a negative. Flip the bits+1 = 0x01. So 0xFFFFFFFF is -1.

Comment: @aliteralmind another thing you tried do is given a number, how to get the negative of that number. In 2's complement (ie. java), you flip the bits and +1. So take the number 1, 0x00000001. To get -1, flip the bits +1 gets you 0xFFFFFFFF. In your example of using MIN_VALUE, you can't get the positive of that because it will overflow. But this is how it works for the rest of the numbers. So even though the MSB is indicative of whether a number is negative, simply setting it to 0 does not give you the positive equivalent number. But it will give you a positive number.

Comment: @anonymous: Thanks, and I appreciate the two's complement information. This is a lot to soak in, but I have a better feel for it after going through all of this. I went farther in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23278164/2736496) earlier today, although I couldn't go too in detail. It was a *lot* of effort, and after I was done, I was informed that I could have saved probably three hours had I known about `Integer.highestOneBit`. But I have a better handle on it now. "Better" anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use Integer.parseInt, you must explicitly determine the sign of the converting value. So if its Integer.MIN_VALUE, for parseInt it looks like this:

```
Integer.parseInt("-10000000000000000000000000000000", 2);
```

— still 32 bits, but with minus as prefix. If no sign is used, the first bit ("sign bit") will be zero (positive value) by default and you will not be able to convert value that consists of more than 31 bits that's why you NumberFormatException — Integer.MAX_VALUE is 01111111111111111111111111111111

Or you may use Integer.parseUnsignedInt :

```
Integer.parseUnsignedInt("10000000000000000000000000000000", 2);
```

Here the binary value will be converted "as is" and the first bit will be interpreted as a sign bit. The result in both cases is -2^31